# FFMPEG Hardware Encoding H264

Tags: video, ffmpeg, live-streaming, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I'm currently trying to use FFMPEG with Hardware/GPU Encoding with the H264 Codec.

What I do is, I pipe raw data direclty into ffmpeg to output them to a udp stream. Those are my settings:

```
var ffmpegArgs = [
    '-c:v', 'rawvideo',// input container
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', // input pixel format
    '-s', '600x600', //input size
    '-video_size', '600x600',
    '-i', 'pipe:0', // input source
    '-f', 'mpegts', // output container format
    '-s', '600x600',
    '-video_size', '600x600',
    '-c:v', 'libx264', // output video codec
    '-b:v', '1m', // output bitrate
    'udp://239.255.123.46:1234' // output destination
];
```

And in generally it is working, but with really miserable quality and latency. The frames are like 5 seconds behind and then have lots of bugs in them so it takes at least 10 or 15 seconds to see the hole frame (the video is a "live stream" from a canvas).

However I thought that GPU Encoding might help here, but I don't get this working. I'm trying to use `VAAPI`, but no matter which command from ffmpeg I'm trying to use (descirbed [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI)), it's not working....

I'm trying to run this on a Intel NUC ([this one](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc5i3ryh.html)) on an Ubuntu 16.04.

Are there any tips on how I can get this running?

Comment: well so I don't think you get hardware encoding with libx264... and you can never have "live" exactly because it needs a temporal sampling in order to do compression... you can use kepler / pascal nvidia cards with the nvenc through ffmpeg, which will reduce latency somewhate.... but really x264 is a pretty fast software encoder, and if you can control your x264 "preset", setting it to `"faster"` will probably make your encoding faster.

Comment: @GradyPlayer where can I set this preset?

Comment: I don't know what your clump of args even means... it would just be one of the options set on the avcontext when you opened the codec... I am not sure how that works from the cli, if that is what those represent (and it looks like they do)

Comment: @GradyPlayer yes, I found the `preset` option in the documentation now, but it seems like the faster the encoding is then, the more quality issues are coming up.. so not sure if this what I need. To get back to the thing you said... In general, it doesn't have to be libx264, it can also be another codec, but with a good quality, for exmaple I tried `mpeg2video`, and encoding is a little faster, but the quality is just not good....

Comment: use `ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24  -framerate 10...`

Answer (score 3):

The encoder you're using, libx264, does not implement hardware-accelerated encoding. Only (some) [OpenCL-accelerated look-ahead function(s)](https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/x264-devel/2013-April/009996.html) are available, and performance gains from that are at best, [marginal](https://www.anandtech.com/show/5835/testing-opencl-accelerated-handbrakex264-with-amds-trinity-apu), especially on high-end systems. To expose look-ahead accelerated look-ahead in that library, ensure that an OpenCL ICD and OpenCL headers are present on the system and that the option `--disable-opencl` is omitted at x264's configuration phase. Likewise, for FFmpeg, ensure that `--enable-opencl` is enabled at the configuration phase.

Take a look at similar answers provided on queries regarding hardware-accelerated encoding with FFmpeg.

1. With [NVENC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55747785/4675388).
2. With [QuickSync](https://superuser.com/a/1428799/473795) (which requires the [Intel Media SDK](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK) to be installed when configuring and building FFmpeg).
3. With [VAAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036502/4675388).

And the [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) on hardware acceleration.