# (FFmpeg) VP9 Vaapi encoding to a .mp4 or .webm container from given official ffmpeg example

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, mp4, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I'm trying to implement vp9 hardware acceleration encoding process. I followed ffmpeg offical github's example ([Here -> vaapi_encode.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/vaapi_encode.c)).

But given example only save a .yuv file to .h264 file, I would like to save the frames to either .mp4 or .webm container. And having the ability to control the quality, and etc.

I'm not reading frames from a file, I'm collecting frames from a live feed.  When having full 5 secs of frames from the live feed, encode those frames using vp9_vaapi to a 5 secs .mp4 file.

I'm able to save all the 5 secs frames from my live feed to a .mp4 or .webm file, but they couldn't be played correctly (more precisely: keep loading, and I open).

The result from the official site's example:

[image]

The cpu encoded vp9 .mp4 file result:

[image]

Edit:
Result
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use FFmpeg directly, where you may optionally add the [vp9_superframe](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#toc-vp9_005fsuperframe) and the [vp9_raw_reorder](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#toc-vp9_005fraw_005freorder) [bitstream filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#toc-Bitstream-Filters) in the same command line if you enable B-frames in the `vp9_vaapi` encoder.

**Example:**

```sh
ffmpeg -threads 4 -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 \
-hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi \
-i http://server:port \
-c:v vp9_vaapi -global_quality 50 -bf 1 \
-bsf:v vp9_raw_reorder,vp9_superframe \
-f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart output%03d.mp4
```

Adjust your input and output paths/urls as needed.

**What this command does:**

It will create 5 second long mp4 segments, via the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment).
See the usage of the `movflags=+faststart` , and how it has been passed as a format option to the underlying mp4 muxer via `-segment_format_options` flag above.

The segment lengths may not be exactly 5 seconds long,  as each segment begins (gets cut on) (with) a keyframe.

However, I'd not recommend enabling B-frames in that encoder, as these bitstream filters have other undesired effects, such as [mucking around with the encoder's rate control](https://github.com/intel/intel-vaapi-driver/issues/284) and [triggering bugs like this one](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6755). This is not desirable in a production environment. This is why the scripts below do not have that option enabled, and instead, we define a set rate control mode directly in the encoder options.

If you need to take advantage of 1:N encoding with VAAPI, use these snippets:

1. If you need to deinterlace, call up the `deinterlace_vaapi` filter:

```sh
    ffmpeg -loglevel debug -threads 4 \
    -init_hw_device vaapi=va:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel vaapi \
    -hwaccel_device va -filter_hw_device va \
    -hwaccel_output_format vaapi \
    -i 'http://server:port' \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]deinterlace_vaapi,split=3[n0][n1][n2]; \
    [n0]scale_vaapi=1152:648[v0]; \
    [n1]scale_vaapi=848:480[v1];
    [n2]scale_vaapi=640:360[v2]" \
    -b:v:0 2250k -maxrate:v:0 2250k -bufsize:v:0 360k -c:v:0 vp9_vaapi -g:v:0 50 -r:v:0 25 -rc_mode:v:0 2 \
    -b:v:1 1750k -maxrate:v:1 1750k -bufsize:v:1 280k -c:v:1 vp9_vaapi -g:v:1 50 -r:v:1 25 -rc_mode:v:1 2 \
    -b:v:2 1000k -maxrate:v:2 1000k -bufsize:v:2 160k -c:v:2 vp9_vaapi -g:v:2 50 -r:v:2 25 -rc_mode:v:2 2 \
    -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 \
    -flags -global_header -f tee -use_fifo 1 \
    -map "[v0]" -map "[v1]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a \
    "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path0/output%03d.mp4| \
     [select=\'v:1,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path1/output%03d.mp4| \
     [select=\'v:2,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path2/output%03d.mp4"
```

2. Without deinterlacing:

```sh
    ffmpeg -loglevel debug -threads 4 \
    -init_hw_device vaapi=va:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel vaapi \
    -hwaccel_device va -filter_hw_device va -hwaccel_output_format vaapi \
    -i 'http://server:port' \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]split=3[n0][n1][n2]; \
    [n0]scale_vaapi=1152:648[v0]; \
    [n1]scale_vaapi=848:480[v1];
    [n2]scale_vaapi=640:360[v2]" \
    -b:v:0 2250k -maxrate:v:0 2250k -bufsize:v:0 2250k -c:v:0 vp9_vaapi -g:v:0 50 -r:v:0 25 -rc_mode:v:0 2  \
    -b:v:1 1750k -maxrate:v:1 1750k -bufsize:v:1 1750k -c:v:1 vp9_vaapi -g:v:1 50 -r:v:1 25 -rc_mode:v:1 2  \
    -b:v:2 1000k -maxrate:v:2 1000k -bufsize:v:2 1000k -c:v:2 vp9_vaapi -g:v:2 50 -r:v:2 25 -rc_mode:v:2 2  \
    -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 \
    -flags -global_header -f tee -use_fifo 1 \
    -map "[v0]" -map "[v1]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a \
    "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path0/output%03d.mp4| \
     [select=\'v:1,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path1/output%03d.mp4| \
     [select=\'v:2,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path2/output%03d.mp4"
```

3. Using Intel's QuickSync (on supported platforms):

On Intel Icelake and above, you can use the `vp9_qsv` encoder wrapper with the following known limitations (for now):

(a). You must enable `low_power mode` because only the VDENC decode path is exposed by the `iHD` driver for now.

(b). Coding option1 and extra_data are not supported by MSDK.

(c). The IVF header will be inserted in MSDK by default, but it is not needed for FFmpeg, and remains disabled by default.

See the examples below:

1. If you need to deinterlace, call up the `vpp_qsv` filter:

```sh
    ffmpeg -nostdin -y -fflags +genpts \
    -init_hw_device vaapi=va:/dev/dri/renderD128,driver=iHD \
    -filter_hw_device va -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi
    -threads 4 -vsync 1 -async 1 \
    -i 'http://server:port' \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]hwmap=derive_device=qsv,format=qsv,vpp_qsv=deinterlace=2:async_depth=4,split[n0][n1][n2]; \
    [n0]vpp_qsv=w=1152:h=648:async_depth=4[v0]; \
    [n1]vpp_qsv=w=848:h=480:async_depth=4[v1];
    [n2]vpp_qsv=w=640:h=360:async_depth=4[v2]" \
    -b:v:0 2250k -maxrate:v:0 2250k -bufsize:v:0 360k -c:v:0 vp9_qsv -g:v:0 50 -r:v:0 25 -low_power:v:0 2 \
    -b:v:1 1750k -maxrate:v:1 1750k -bufsize:v:1 280k -c:v:1 vp9_qsv -g:v:1 50 -r:v:1 25 -low_power:v:1 2 \
    -b:v:2 1000k -maxrate:v:2 1000k -bufsize:v:2 160k -c:v:2 vp9_qsv -g:v:2 50 -r:v:2 25 -low_power:v:2 2 \
    -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 \
    -flags -global_header -f tee -use_fifo 1 \
    -map "[v0]" -map "[v1]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a \
    "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path0/output%03d.mp4| \
     [select=\'v:1,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path1/output%03d.mp4| \
     [select=\'v:2,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path2/output%03d.mp4"
```

2. Without deinterlacing:

```sh
    ffmpeg -nostdin -y -fflags +genpts \
    -init_hw_device vaapi=va:/dev/dri/renderD128,driver=iHD \
    -filter_hw_device va -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi
    -threads 4 -vsync 1 -async 1 \
    -i 'http://server:port' \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]hwmap=derive_device=qsv,format=qsv,split=3[n0][n1][n2]; \
    [n0]vpp_qsv=w=1152:h=648:async_depth=4[v0]; \
    [n1]vpp_qsv=w=848:h=480:async_depth=4[v1];
    [n2]vpp_qsv=w=640:h=360:async_depth=4[v2]" \
    -b:v:0 2250k -maxrate:v:0 2250k -bufsize:v:0 2250k -c:v:0 vp9_qsv -g:v:0 50 -r:v:0 25 -low_power:v:0 2  \
    -b:v:1 1750k -maxrate:v:1 1750k -bufsize:v:1 1750k -c:v:1 vp9_qsv -g:v:1 50 -r:v:1 25 -low_power:v:1 2  \
    -b:v:2 1000k -maxrate:v:2 1000k -bufsize:v:2 1000k -c:v:2 vp9_qsv -g:v:2 50 -r:v:2 25 -low_power:v:2 2  \
    -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 \
    -flags -global_header -f tee -use_fifo 1 \
    -map "[v0]" -map "[v1]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a \
    "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path0/output%03d.mp4| \
     [select=\'v:1,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path1/output%03d.mp4| \
     [select=\'v:2,a\':f=segment:segment_time=5:segment_format_options=movflags=+faststart]$output_path2/output%03d.mp4"
```

Note that we use the `vpp_qsv filter` with the `async_depth` option set to 4. This massively improves transcode performance over using `scale_qsv` and `deinterlace_qsv`. See [this commit](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/89ffcd1bbe1150aa07ae52a4e1545668a4e83a3e) on FFmpeg's git.

**Note:** If you use the QuickSync path, note that MFE (Multi-Frame encoding mode) will be enabled by default if the Media SDK library on your system supports it.

**Formulae used to derive the snippet above:**

Optimal bufsize:v = target bitrate (-b:v value)

Set GOP size as: 2 * fps (GOP interval set to 2 seconds).

We limit the thread counts for the video encoder(s) via `-threads:v` to prevent VBV overflows.

Resolution ladder used: 640p, 480p and 360p in 16:9, see [this](https://pacoup.com/2011/06/12/list-of-true-169-resolutions/) link.
Adjust this as needed.

Substitute the variables above (`$output_path{0-2}`, the input, etc) as needed.

Test and report back.

**Current observations:**

On my system, I'm able to encode up to 5 streams at real-time with VP9 using [Apple's recommended resolutions and bit-rates for HEVC encoding for HLS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices) as a benchmark. See the picture below on system load, etc.

[image: system load and stats with 5 simultaneous VAAPI encodes in progress]

**Platform details:**

I'm on a Coffee-lake system, using the `i965` driver for this workflow:

```sh
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'i965'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_5
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.5 (libva 2.4.0.pre1)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Coffee Lake - 2.4.0.pre1 (2.3.0-11-g881e67a)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

My ffmpeg build info:

```sh
ffmpeg -buildconf
ffmpeg version N-93308-g1144d5c96d Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/home/brainiarc7/bin --bindir=/home/brainiarc7/bin --extra-cflags=-I/home/brainiarc7/bin/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/brainiarc7/bin/lib --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ --enable-nvenc --extra-cflags=-I/opt/intel/mediasdk/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/intel/mediasdk/lib --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/intel/mediasdk/plugins --enable-libmfx --enable-libass --enable-vaapi --disable-debug --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libdrm --enable-opencl --enable-gpl --cpu=native --enable-opengl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx265 --enable-openssl --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.103 / 58. 47.103
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100

  configuration:
    --pkg-config-flags=--static
    --prefix=/home/brainiarc7/bin
    --bindir=/home/brainiarc7/bin
    --extra-cflags=-I/home/brainiarc7/bin/include
    --extra-ldflags=-L/home/brainiarc7/bin/lib
    --enable-cuda-nvcc
    --enable-cuvid
    --enable-libnpp
    --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include/
    --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
    --enable-nvenc
    --extra-cflags=-I/opt/intel/mediasdk/include
    --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/intel/mediasdk/lib
    --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/intel/mediasdk/plugins
    --enable-libmfx
    --enable-libass
    --enable-vaapi
    --disable-debug
    --enable-libvorbis
    --enable-libvpx
    --enable-libdrm
    --enable-opencl
    --enable-gpl
    --cpu=native
    --enable-opengl
    --enable-libfdk-aac
    --enable-libx265
    --enable-openssl
    --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm'
    --enable-nonfree
```

And output from inxi:

```sh
inxi -F
System:    Host: cavaliere Kernel: 5.0.0 x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: ASUSTeK product: Zephyrus M GM501GS v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: GM501GS v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: GM501GS.308 date: 10/01/2018
Battery    BAT0: charge: 49.3 Wh 100.0% condition: 49.3/55.0 Wh (90%)
CPU:       6 core Intel Core i7-8750H (-MT-MCP-) cache: 9216 KB
           clock speeds: max: 4100 MHz 1: 2594 MHz 2: 3197 MHz 3: 3633 MHz 4: 3514 MHz 5: 3582 MHz 6: 3338 MHz
           7: 3655 MHz 8: 3684 MHz 9: 1793 MHz 10: 3651 MHz 11: 3710 MHz 12: 3662 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 3e9b
           Card-2: NVIDIA GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: modesetting,nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@144.03hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.43
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA v: k5.0.0
           Card-2 NVIDIA GP104 High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-3 Kingston driver: USB Audio
Network:   Card: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: (redacted)
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 3050.6GB (94.5% used)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: Samsung_SSD_960_EVO_1TB size: 1000.2GB
           ID-2: /dev/sda model: Crucial_CT2050MX size: 2050.4GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 246G used: 217G (94%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.59GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 64.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 61C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 412 Uptime: 3:32 Memory: 4411.3/32015.5MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

**Why that last bit is included:**

I'm running the latest Linux kernel to date, version 5.0.
The same also applies to the graphics driver stack, on Ubuntu 18.04LTS.
FFmpeg was built as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/5fbecef51470d2d25a0747444abc2c53) as this laptop has both NVIDIA+ Intel GPU enabled via Optimus. That way, I can tap into VAAPI, QuickSync and NVENC hwaccels as needed. **Your mileage may vary** even if our hardware is identical.

**References:**

1. See the encoder options, including rate control methods supported:

```sh
ffmpeg -h encoder=vp9_vaapi
```

2. See the deinterlace_vaapi filter usage options:

```sh
ffmpeg -h filter=deinterlace_vaapi
```

3. On the `vpp_qsv` filter usage, see:

```sh
ffmpeg -h filter=vpp_qsv
```

For instance, if you want field-rate output rather than frame-rate output from the deinterlacer, you could pass the `rate=field` option to it instead:

```sh
-vf=vaapi_deinterlace=rate=field
```

This feature, for instance, is tied to encoders that support [MBAFF](https://www.afterdawn.com/glossary/term.cfm/macroblock-adaptive_frame-field_coding). Others, such as the NVENC-based ones in FFmpeg, [do not have this implemented](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7080) (as of the time of writing).

**Tips on getting ahead with FFmpeg:**

Where possible, infer to the built-in docs, as with the examples shown above.
They can uncover potential pitfalls that you may be able to avoid by understanding how filter chaining and encoder initialization works, unsupported features, etc, and the impact on performance.

For example, you'll see that in the snippets above, we call up the deinterlacer only once, then split its' output via the `split` filter to separate scalers. This is done to lower the overhead that would be incurred had we called up the deinterlacer more than once, and it would've been wasteful.

**Warning:**

Note that the SDK requires at least 2 threads to prevent deadlock, see [this](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/blob/master/_studio/mfx_lib/scheduler/linux/src/mfx_scheduler_core_ischeduler.cpp#L90-L93) code block. This is why we set `-threads 4` in ffmpeg.

Comment: Thats great news to just use FFmpeg directly.  Your command line takes a .mp4 input, do you know how can you encode a live stream (ip camera) to 5 secs of videos every 5 secs using FFmpeg directly?

Comment: I've successfully encoded live feed from an ip camera by changing input.mp4 to the http address. Any idea on how to make it only encode 5s clips and stop?

Comment: Typically you'll need to segment. A bit busy at the moment but I'll provide a solution to this as soon as I'm able. Bear with me :-)

Comment: Definitely, much appreaciated

Comment: Just a side note, I'm encoding videos in low res and wish to do the encoding task in real time.   I wonder with higher res, like 1080p, can vaapi encodes clips in real time? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. However, watch out for possible GPU hangs, especially if you're on an older Linux kernel. I've been able to encode up to 8 H.264/AVC streams on kabylake with faster than real-time performance, see https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/4f831867f8e55d35cbcb527e15f9f116 for examples

Comment: I was following your older post since I'm using ubuntu 16.04 (https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/24de2edef08866c304080504877239a3).  I'm only using vaapi for h264 and vp9 encoding,  I wonder does it have any performance difference between the 16.04 ffmpeg build without the intel qsv and the 18.04 ffmpeg build with the extra intel qsv stuff?

Comment: I think I'm seeing the gpu hang thing as you mentioned.  The second encoded clip seems frozed and then the clip start playing after few seconds.  I also notice the playback speed is faster than normal, is there anyway I can adjust the playback speed?  And for gpu hang I should move 16.04 to 18.04 to solve it?

Comment: I've uploaded a picture of information while doing the encoding, does it provide any clue to the playback speed problem? Maybe cuz the low fps?  Thank you.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, only the open source VAAPI driver (i965) has support for VP9. The proprietary driver packaged for the Media SDK (iHD) most likely doesn't support VP9 encoding. Running vainfo and filtering for Slice (vainfo | grep Slice) with the selected driver should show you what's supported. Let me generate an ffmpeg snippet with the requested features.

Comment: Thank you! BTW, the source live feed of mine is streaming at 25fps, but encoding process only have like 5fps while using vaapi for real time encoding. Is this normal?

Comment: It can be the case, depending on how you're calling up ffmpeg and the software stack that's on your system. Older kernels will definitely perform far worse than newer ones, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the informative update, will def. test the performance difference between the two kernels.  Youre a god of FFmpeg hands down

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! Do confirm that the output quality is acceptable with these settings. YMMV based on the content you're encoding. Let us know if you run into issues with the snippets above.

Comment: On current Icelake+ H/W, you can use the QSV wrappers for the same,  as documented here: https://superuser.com/a/1644371/473795