# How to use GPU to accelerate the processing speed of ffmpeg filter?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nvidia

According to NVIDIA's developer website, you can use GPU to speed up the rendering of the ffmpeg filter.

> Create high-performance end-to-end hardware-accelerated video
> processing, 1:N encoding and 1:N transcoding pipeline using built-in > filters in FFmpeg
>
> Ability to add your own custom high-performance CUDA filters using
> the shared CUDA context implementation in FFmpeg

**The problem I am having now is how to use the GPU to speed up multiple ffmpeg filter processing?**

For example:

```sh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i dog.jpg -filter_complex "scale=iw*4:-1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.002':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=720x960" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -y -r:v 25 -t 5 -crf 28 dog.mp4
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When it comes to hardware acceleration in FFmpeg, you can expect the following implementations by type:

**1. Hardware-accelerated encoders:** In the case of NVIDIA, NVENC is supported and implemented via the h264_nvenc and the hevc_nvenc wrappers. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1296374/best-settings-for-ffmpeg-with-nvenc/1296511#1296511) answer on how to tune them, and any limitations you may run into depending on the generation of hardware you're on.

**2. Hardware-accelerated filters:** Filters that perform duties such as [scaling](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling) and post-processing (deinterlacing, etc) are available in FFmpeg, and some implementations are hardware-accelerated. For NVIDIA, the following filters can take advantage of hardware-acceleration:

(a). [scale_cuda](https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/patch/3651/): This is a scaling filter analogous to the generic scale filter, implemented in CUDA. It's dependency is the [ffnvcodec](https://github.com/FFmpeg/nv-codec-headers) project, headers needed to also enable the NVENC-based encoders. When the ffnvcodec headers are present, the respective filters dependent on it (scale_cuda and yadif_cuda) will be automatically enabled. In production, it may be wise to deprecate this filter in favor of `scale_npp` as it has a very limited set of options.

(b). [scale_npp](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-scale_005fnpp): This is a scaling filter implemented in [NVIDIA's Performance Primitives](https://developer.nvidia.com/npp). It's primary dependency is the [CUDA SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads), and it must be explicitly enabled by passing `--enable-libnpp`, `--enable-cuda-nvcc` and `--enable-nonfree` flags to `./configure` at compile time when building FFmpeg from source. Use this filter in place of `scale_cuda` wherever possible.

(c). [yadif_cuda](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif_005fcuda): This is a deinterlacer, implemented in CUDA. It's dependency, as stated above, is the ffnvcodec package of headers.

(d). **All OpenCL-based filters:** All NVENC-capable GPUs supported by both the mainline NVIDIA driver and the CUDA SDK implement OpenCL support. I started this section with this clarification because there's news in the wind that NVIDIA will be [deprecating mobile Kepler GPUs in their mainline driver](https://www.anandtech.com/show/14067/nvidia-to-move-mobile-kepler-gpus-to-legacy-status-in-april-2019), relegating them to Legacy support status. For this reason, if you're on such a  platform, take this into consideration.

To enable these filters, pass `--enable-opencl` to  FFmpeg's `./configure` script at build time. Note that this requires the OpenCL headers to be present on your system, and can be safely satisfied by your package manager on whatever Linux distribution you're on. On other operating systems, your mileage may vary.

To see all OpenCL-based filters, run:

```
ffmpeg -h filters | grep opencl
```

A few notable examples being `unsharp_opencl`,`avgblur_opencl`, etc. See [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-Video-options) wiki section for more options.

**(e). All Vulkan-based filters:**

If FFmpeg is built with support for the [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) back-end, new filters will be available, which can be listed via:

```
ffmpeg -filters | grep vulkan
```

These filters are mostly beneficial for VAAPI and AMD's AMF interoperability, where shared HWContexts can be used to massively speed up functions such as scaling, etc. AMD's use case, in particular, allows you to perform hardware-accelerated scaling with Vulkan, which is critical for real-time throughput with the AMF's encoders because the current implementation of AMF in FFmpeg lacks scaling filters. This could change in the future as [Khronos finishes up on Vulkan extensions for video encoding](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Vulkan-Video-Decode-H1-2020).

An example of a Vulkan-based scale filter with FFmpeg running on an NVIDIA GPU with NVDEC H/W acceleration with NVENC encoding is shown below:

```sh
ffmpeg -threads 1 -loglevel info -nostdin -y \
   -fflags +genpts-fastseek \
   -init_hw_device cuda=cuda:0 -filter_hw_device cuda \
   -hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 3 \
   -reinit_filter 1 -vsync 1 -async 1 -filter_threads 2 -filter_complex_threads 2 \
   -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
  "[0:v]hwupload=derive_device=vulkan,split=2[s0][s1]; \
   [s0]scale_vulkan=w=1920:h=1080:scaler=0,hwupload=derive_device=cuda[v0]; \
   [s1]scale_vulkan=w=1280:h=720:scaler=0,hwupload=derive_device=cuda[v1]" \
  -map "[v0]" -b:v:0 5800k -minrate:v:0 5800k -maxrate:v:0 5800k -bufsize:v:0 5800k -c:v:0 h264_nvenc -r:v:0 ntsc \
  -profile:v:0 high -preset:v:0 llhp -rc:v:0 cbr_ld_hq -g:v:0 60 -gpu:v:0 0 -strict_gop:v:0 1 -bf:v:0 0 \
  -map "[v1]"  -b:v:1 4000k -minrate:v:1 4000k -maxrate:v:1 4000k -bufsize:v:1 4000k -c:v:1 h264_nvenc -r:v:1 ntsc \
  -profile:v:1 high -preset:v:1 llhp -rc:v:1 cbr_ld_hq -g:v:1 60 -gpu:v:1 0 -strict_gop:v:1 1 -bf:v:1 0 \
  -map 0:a -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k \
  -flags +global_header+cgop \
  -max_muxing_queue_size 9000000 -f tee  \
  "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=mp4]'hq.mp4'| \
   [select=\'v:1,a\':f=mp4]'med.mp4'"
```

See how the snippet above utilizes [hwupload](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hwupload-1)'s filter's device derivation capability to insert a Vulkan H/W context into the complex filter chain.

**A note pertaining to performance with OpenCL and Vulkan-based filters:** Please take into account any overheads that mechanisms introduced by filter chains such as `hwupload` and `hwdownload` may introduce into your pipeline, as uploading textures to and from system memory and the accelerator in question will affect performance, and so will format conversion operations (via the `format` filter) where needed/required.
In this case, it may be beneficial to take advantage of the [`hwmap`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hwmap) filter, and deriving contexts where applicable. For instance, VAAPI has a mechanism that allows for OpenCL device derivation and reverse mapping via `hwmap`, if the [`cl_intel_va_api_media_sharing` OpenCL extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/intel/cl_intel_va_api_media_sharing.txt) is present. This is typically provided by the [Beignet ICD](https://github.com/intel/beignet), and is absent in others, such as  the newer [Neo OpenCL driver](https://01.org/compute-runtime).

**3. Hardware-accelerated decoders (and their associated wrappers):** Depending on your input source, and the capabilities of your NVIDIA GPU, based on generation, you may also tap into hardware accelerations based on either CUVID or NVDEC. These methods differ in how they handle textures in-flight on the accelerator, and it is wise to evaluate other factors, such as VRAM utilization, when they are in use.
Typically, you can take advantage of the CUVID-based hwaccels for operations such as deinterlacing, if so desired. See their usage  via:

```
ffmpeg -h decoder=h264_cuvid
ffmpeg -h decoder=hevc_cuvid
ffmpeg -h decoder=mpeg2_cuvid
```

However, beware that handling [MBAFF](https://www.afterdawn.com/glossary/term.cfm/macroblock-adaptive_frame-field_coding) encoded content with these decoders, where double deinterlacing is required, is not advisable as NVIDIA has not yet implemented MBAFF support in the backend. Take a look at [this thread](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6971) for more on the same.

**In closing:** It is wise to evaluate where and when hardware accelerated offloading (filtering, encoding and decoding) offers an advantage or an acceptable trade-off (in quality, feature support and reliability) in your pipeline prior to deployment in production. This is a vendor-neutral approach when deciding what and when to offload parts of your  pipeline, and the same applies to NVIDIA's solutions.

For more information, refer to the [hardware acceleration entry in FFmpeg's wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro).

**Warning:** Be sure to lower the decoder's thread count to 1. These hwaccels, particularly cuvid (and the nvdec wrapper) do not implement threading support. In fact, they'll [throw warnings](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/nvdec.c#L399) at you if the thread  count exceeds 32. For these decoders, thread count(s) explicitly assume the surface count.

Pass `-threads 1` to ffmpeg **before** input. The argument position of threads is important. In this case, it sets the thread count for the decoder to 1. After the input, it sets the thread count used by FFmpeg's encoders and muxers (if threading is supported) to the configured value.

Also note the usage of a new parameter `-extra_hw_frames 3` passed directly to FFmpeg when using NVDEC. This is done to ensure that the surface pool allocated to the decoder and encoder instances is sufficient, typically the case where other filters are chained along such as deinterlacing with `yadif_cuda`, `scale_npp`, etc. See [this ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7562) for more information.

**Samples demonstrating the use of hardware-accelerated filtering, encoding and decoding based on the notes above:**

**1. Demonstrate the use of 1:N encoding with NVENC:**

The following assumption is made: The test-bed only has one NVENC-capable GPU present, a simple GTX 1070. For this reason I'm limited to two simultaneous NVENC sessions, and that is taken into account with the snippets below.
Be warned that cases needing to utilize multiple NVENC-capable GPUs will need the command line(s) modified as appropriate.

My sample files are in `~/Desktop/src`

I'll be working with a sample file as shown below:

```sh
ffprobe -i deint-testfile.mkv -show_format -hide_banner -show_streams
```

```sh
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'deint-testfile.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.3 + libmatroska v1.4.4
    creation_time   : 2016-03-02T23:20:05.000000Z
  Duration: 00:04:56.97, start: 0.066000, bitrate: 31036 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 29131349
      BPS-eng         : 29131349
      DURATION        : 00:04:56.896000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:04:56.896000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 17598
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 17598
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 1081122637
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1081122637
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-03-02 23:20:05
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-03-02 23:20:05
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1: Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32p (24 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 1907258
      BPS-eng         : 1907258
      DURATION        : 00:04:56.896000000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:04:56.896000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 27834
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 27834
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 70782196
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 70782196
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2016-03-02 23:20:05
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2016-03-02 23:20:05
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=317/38002
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1088
has_b_frames=1
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=41
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=left
field_order=tt
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=19001/317
avg_frame_rate=19001/317
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=66
start_time=0.066000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:BPS=29131349
TAG:BPS-eng=29131349
TAG:DURATION=00:04:56.896000000
TAG:DURATION-eng=00:04:56.896000000
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES=17598
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng=17598
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES=1081122637
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng=1081122637
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP=mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng=mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC=2016-03-02 23:20:05
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng=2016-03-02 23:20:05
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS-eng=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=dts
codec_long_name=DCA (DTS Coherent Acoustics)
profile=DTS-HD MA
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=s32p
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=76
start_time=0.076000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=24
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:BPS=1907258
TAG:BPS-eng=1907258
TAG:DURATION=00:04:56.896000000
TAG:DURATION-eng=00:04:56.896000000
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES=27834
TAG:NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng=27834
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES=70782196
TAG:NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng=70782196
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP=mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng=mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC=2016-03-02 23:20:05
TAG:_STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng=2016-03-02 23:20:05
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
TAG:_STATISTICS_TAGS-eng=BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=deint-testfile.mkv
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=matroska,webm
format_long_name=Matroska / WebM
start_time=0.066000
duration=296.972000
size=1152134036
bit_rate=31036839
probe_score=100
TAG:encoder=libebml v1.3.3 + libmatroska v1.4.4
TAG:creation_time=2016-03-02T23:20:05.000000Z
[/FORMAT]
```

With that information, we can tell that the input file is deinterlaced, encoded at 59.94 FPS.
In the examples below, I'll target the same frame rate, using a closed GOP, assuming a fixed keyframe distance of 2 seconds (set by `-g 120` where `-r=60`).

I can run this encoder sample as shown, demonstrating two use cases:

1. Use the cuvid-based decoder (h264_cuvid) as the deinterlacer (Note that the input format is H.264/AVC and as such, we're using the correct decoder):

```sh
   ffmpeg -threads 1 -fflags +genpts -y -c:v h264_cuvid -surfaces 8 -deint 2 -drop_second_field 1 -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 3 \
   -i 'deint-testfile.mkv' -filter_complex \
  "[0:v:0]split=2[a][b]; \
   [a]scale_npp=w=1280:h=720:interp_algo=super[c]; \
   [b]scale_npp=w=640:h=360:interp_algo=super[d]" \
   -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -vsync 1 -async 1 \
  -b:v:0 6000k -minrate:v:0 6000k -maxrate:v:0 6000k -bufsize:v:0 400k -c:v:0 h264_nvenc \
  -profile:v:0 high -rc:v:0 cbr_ld_hq -level:v:0 4.2 -r:v:0 59.94 -g:v:0 120 -bf:v:0 3 -strict_gop:v:0 1 \
  -b:v:1 4200k -minrate:v:1 4200k -maxrate:v:1 4200k -bufsize:v:1 280k -c:v:1 h264_nvenc \
  -profile:v:1 high -rc:v:1 cbr_ld_hq -level:v:1 4.2 -r:v:1 59.94 -g:v:1 120 -bf:v:1 3 -strict_gop:v:1 1 \
  -flags +global_header+cgop \
  -map "[c]" -map "[d]" -map a:0 \
  -f tee  \
  "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=flv]"/home/brainiarc7/Desktop/src/cheeks0.flv"| \
   [select=\'v:1,a\':f=flv]"/home/brainiarc7/Desktop/src/cheeks1.flv""
```

**2. Use the nvdec hwaccel paired with the yadif_cuda deinterlacer:**

```sh
   ffmpeg -threads 1 -fflags +genpts -y -hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 3 \
   -i 'deint-testfile.mkv' -filter_complex \
  "[0:v:0]yadif_cuda=0:-1:1,split=2[a][b]; \
   [a]scale_npp=w=1280:h=720:interp_algo=super[c]; \
   [b]scale_npp=w=640:h=360:interp_algo=super[d]" \
   -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -vsync 1 -async 1 \
  -b:v:0 6000k -minrate:v:0 6000k -maxrate:v:0 6000k -bufsize:v:0 400k -c:v:0 h264_nvenc \
  -profile:v:0 high -rc:v:0 cbr_ld_hq -level:v:0 4.2 -r:v:0 59.94 -g:v:0 120 -bf:v:0 3 -strict_gop:v:0 1 \
  -b:v:1 4200k -minrate:v:1 4200k -maxrate:v:1 4200k -bufsize:v:1 280k -c:v:1 h264_nvenc \
  -profile:v:1 high -rc:v:1 cbr_ld_hq -level:v:1 4.2 -r:v:1 59.94 -g:v:1 120 -bf:v:1 3 -strict_gop:v:1 1 \
  -flags +global_header+cgop \
  -map "[c]" -map "[d]" -map a:0 \
  -f tee  \
  "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=flv]"/home/brainiarc7/Desktop/src/cheeks0.flv"| \
   [select=\'v:1,a\':f=flv]"/home/brainiarc7/Desktop/src/cheeks1.flv""
```

You can use an extra filter before the `yadif_cuda` deinterlacer, `hwupload_cuda` in cases where hardware accelerated decode is undesirable.
When you call up the `hwupload_cuda` filter, it automatically creates a device type cuda, converts all in-flight textures to the cuda format and uploads them to the shared CUDA hardware context from which the latter filter `yadif_cuda` can operate on.
However, if you pass the option `-hwaccel_output_format cuda` you can skip this extra `hwupload_cuda` filter. This is the preferred method for maximum throughput.

The options specified for the `yadif_cuda` filter are:

(a). Set the deinterlaing mode as send one frame for each frame.

(b). Set the assumed picture type parity as automatic.

(c). To only deinterlace frames marked as deinterlaced.

You can confirm this by running:

```sh
ffmpeg -h filter=yadif_cuda
```

You can also attempt [double de-interlacing](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Deinterlacing#Double_Framerate) (wherein the de-interlacer sends one frame per field, instead of one frame per frame) by applying the deinterlacer options below.(see the filter options passed in `yadif_cuda=1:-1:1`):

```sh
   ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -y -hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_output_format cuda \
   -threads 1 -extra_hw_frames 3 \
   -i 'deint-testfile.mkv' -filter_complex \
  "[0:v:0]yadif_cuda=1:-1:1,split=2[a][b]; \
   [a]scale_npp=w=1280:h=720:interp_algo=lanczos[c]; \
   [b]scale_npp=w=640:h=360:interp_algo=lanczos[d]" \
   -af "aresample=async=1000:min_hard_comp=0.100000" -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -vsync 1 \
  -b:v:0 6000k -minrate:v:0 6000k -maxrate:v:0 6000k -bufsize:v:0 400k -c:v:0 h264_nvenc \
  -profile:v:0 high -rc:v:0 cbr_ld_hq -level:v:0 4.2 -r:v:0 59.94 -g:v:0 120 -bf:v:0 3 -strict_gop:v:0 1 \
  -b:v:1 4200k -minrate:v:1 4200k -maxrate:v:1 4200k -bufsize:v:1 280k -c:v:1 h264_nvenc \
  -profile:v:1 high -rc:v:1 cbr_ld_hq -level:v:1 4.2 -r:v:1 59.94 -g:v:1 120 -bf:v:1 3 -strict_gop:v:1 1 \
  -flags +global_header \
  -map "[c]" -map "[d]" -map a:0 \
  -f tee  \
  "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=flv]"/home/brainiarc7/Desktop/src/cheeks0.flv"| \
   [select=\'v:1,a\':f=flv]"/home/brainiarc7/Desktop/src/cheeks1.flv""
```

However, be cautious with this option as it may fail at some specific frame rates. In my testing, using NTSC interlaced content at 29.970 FPS resulted in failure when attempting a double deinterlace.
Your mileage may vary.

**3. Demonstrating the use of an OpenCL filter with the NVIDIA GPU:**

The filter we will use in this case is the `tonemap_opencl`, with the following usage options:

```sh
ffmpeg -h filter=tonemap_opencl
```

```
Filter tonemap_opencl
  perform HDR to SDR conversion with tonemapping
    Inputs:
       #0: default (video)
    Outputs:
       #0: default (video)
tonemap_opencl AVOptions:
  tonemap           <int>        ..FV..... tonemap algorithm selection (from 0 to 6) (default none)
     none                         ..FV.....
     linear                       ..FV.....
     gamma                        ..FV.....
     clip                         ..FV.....
     reinhard                     ..FV.....
     hable                        ..FV.....
     mobius                       ..FV.....
  transfer          <int>        ..FV..... set transfer characteristic (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default bt709)
     bt709                        ..FV.....
     bt2020                       ..FV.....
  t                 <int>        ..FV..... set transfer characteristic (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default bt709)
     bt709                        ..FV.....
     bt2020                       ..FV.....
  matrix            <int>        ..FV..... set colorspace matrix (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
     bt709                        ..FV.....
     bt2020                       ..FV.....
  m                 <int>        ..FV..... set colorspace matrix (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
     bt709                        ..FV.....
     bt2020                       ..FV.....
  primaries         <int>        ..FV..... set color primaries (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
     bt709                        ..FV.....
     bt2020                       ..FV.....
  p                 <int>        ..FV..... set color primaries (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
     bt709                        ..FV.....
     bt2020                       ..FV.....
  range             <int>        ..FV..... set color range (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
     tv                           ..FV.....
     pc                           ..FV.....
     limited                      ..FV.....
     full                         ..FV.....
  r                 <int>        ..FV..... set color range (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
     tv                           ..FV.....
     pc                           ..FV.....
     limited                      ..FV.....
     full                         ..FV.....
  format            <pix_fmt>    ..FV..... output pixel format (default none)
  peak              <double>     ..FV..... signal peak override (from 0 to DBL_MAX) (default 0)
  param             <double>     ..FV..... tonemap parameter (from DBL_MIN to DBL_MAX) (default nan)
  desat             <double>     ..FV..... desaturation parameter (from 0 to DBL_MAX) (default 0.5)
  threshold         <double>     ..FV..... scene detection threshold (from 0 to DBL_MAX) (default 0.2)
```

The sample file in use has HDR metadata embedded, and using the NVENC encoders, will be encoded to a pair of outputs with tone-mapping applied.
The sample file used is from [this](https://4kmedia.org/lg-new-york-hdr-uhd-4k-demo/) URL.

From ffprobe:

```
ffprobe -i lgnyhdrdemo.ts -show_streams -hide_banner -show_format
[mpegts @ 0x55f34f8bbf80] start time for stream 1 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x55f34f8bbf80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'lgnyhdrdemo.ts':
  Duration: 00:01:12.24, start: 0.999989, bitrate: 52032 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x101]: Video: hevc (Main 10) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x102](und): Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 0 channels
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=hevc
codec_long_name=H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding)
profile=Main 10
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/25
codec_tag_string=[36][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0024
width=3840
height=2160
coded_width=3840
coded_height=2160
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p10le
level=150
color_range=tv
color_space=bt2020nc
color_transfer=smpte2084
color_primaries=bt2020
chroma_location=unspecified
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=0x101
r_frame_rate=25/1
avg_frame_rate=25/1
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=89999
start_time=0.999989
duration_ts=6501600
duration=72.240000
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/0
codec_tag_string=[15][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x000f
sample_fmt=unknown
sample_rate=0
channels=0
channel_layout=unknown
bits_per_sample=0
id=0x102
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=89999
start_time=0.999989
duration_ts=6501600
duration=72.240000
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=lgnyhdrdemo.ts
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=1
format_name=mpegts
format_long_name=MPEG-TS (MPEG-2 Transport Stream)
start_time=0.999989
duration=72.240000
size=469857120
bit_rate=52032903
probe_score=50
[/FORMAT]
```

Now let us apply the `tonemap_opencl` filter to the previous command, switching to the new input file, and timing the command:

```sh
   time ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -y -hwaccel nvdec -init_hw_device opencl=ocl -filter_hw_device ocl \
   -threads 1 -extra_hw_frames 3 \
   -i 'lgnyhdrdemo.ts' -filter_complex \
  "[0:v:0]hwupload,tonemap_opencl=t=bt2020:tonemap=hable:desat=0:format=nv12,hwupload_cuda,split=2[a][b]; \
   [a]scale_npp=w=1280:h=720:interp_algo=lanczos[c]; \
   [b]scale_npp=w=640:h=360:interp_algo=lanczos[d]" \
   -af "aresample=async=1000:min_hard_comp=0.100000" -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -vsync 1 \
  -b:v:0 6000k -minrate:v:0 6000k -maxrate:v:0 6000k -bufsize:v:0 480k -c:v:0 h264_nvenc \
  -profile:v:0 high -rc:v:0 cbr_ld_hq -level:v:0 4.2 -r:v:0 25 -g:v:0 50 -bf:v:0 3 -strict_gop:v:0 1 \
  -b:v:1 4200k -minrate:v:1 4200k -maxrate:v:1 4200k -bufsize:v:1 672k -c:v:1 h264_nvenc \
  -profile:v:1 high -rc:v:1 cbr_ld_hq -level:v:1 4.2 -r:v:1 25 -g:v:1 50 -bf:v:1 3 -strict_gop:v:1 1 \
  -flags +global_header \
  -map "[c]" -map "[d]" -map a:0 \
  -f tee  \
  "[select=\'v:0,a\':f=flv]"/home/brainiarc7/Desktop/src/tonemapped0.flv"| \
   [select=\'v:1,a\':f=flv]"/home/brainiarc7/Desktop/src/tonemapped1.flv""
```

According to FFmpeg, that took:

```
frame= 1806 fps= 37 q=2.0 Lq=2.0 size=N/A time=00:01:12.20 bitrate=N/A speed=1.49x      
video:84533kB audio:1068kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[aac @ 0x562e85cc9b00] Qavg: 4252.148

real    0m48.894s
user    0m45.710s
sys 0m17.049s
```

For more on tone-mapping, see [this](https://stevens.li/guides/video/converting-hdr-to-sdr-with-ffmpeg/) excellent write-up.

Comment: I got `Unknown option "--enable-cuda-nvcc"` on ffmpeg 4.14 source

Comment: Build from git, master branch.

Comment: Side note to this: scale_npp is effectively deprecated in favour of scale_cuda.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile your own ffmpeg build using their extensions - see https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg for instructions as the standard binary does not include these capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution. Untested, so let me know of any errors...

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -hwaccel NVENC -loop 1 -i dog.jpg -filter_complex "scale=iw*4:-1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.002':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=720x960" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec h264_nvenc -preset ultrafast -y -r:v 25 -t 5 -crf 28 dog.mp4
```

Where you...

- Initialize NVIDIA encoding by `-hwaccel NVENC`.
- Set codec as `-vcodec h264_nvenc`.

Comment: command error

```shell
Pixel format 'yuvj420p' is not supported
```

Comment: (1) Try with the latest FFmpeg version because 'yuvj420p' is deprecated and replaced by `yuv420p`. Which part of my Answer is it coming from? (2) Remove `-preset ultrafast` just in case the preset is overriding your other settings. (3) Put `-y` at start like `ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug ...etc`.

Comment: `-loglevel debug` is useful for troubleshooting; thank you!