# Pass ffpmeg OpenCL filter output to NVenc without hwdownload?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, opencl, nvidia, nvenc

I'm trying to do tonemapping (and resizing) of a UHD HDR video stream with ffmpeg. The following command:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -init_hw_device opencl=ocl -filter_hw_device ocl 
    -threads 1 -extra_hw_frames 3 -c:v hevc_cuvid -resize 1920x1080 -i "INPUT.hevc" 
    -vf "hwupload,
         tonemap_opencl=tonemap=mobius:param=0.01:desat=0:r=tv:p=bt709:t=bt709:m=bt709:format=nv12,
         hwdownload,format=nv12,hwupload_cuda" 
    -c:v hevc_nvenc -b:v 8M "OUTPUT.hevc"
```

seems to work (around 200 FPS on an RTX 3080). However, I notice that it still uses one CPU core and the GPU usage is reported only as 60-70%. When I only resize without any filters I get around 400FPS with 100% GPU usage.

I suspect that the last `hwdownload,format=nv12,hwupload_cuda` statements are a problem, because this adds a detour through main memory. I tried just using `hwupload_cuda` instead without the `hwdownload` (like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55747785/929037 in the filter example near the end of this answer), but then I got the following error:

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_tonemap_opencl_1' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Trying to use `hwmap` resulted in

```
Assertion dst->format == AV_PIX_FMT_OPENCL failed at C:/code/ffmpeg/src/libavutil/hwcontext_opencl.c:2814
```

Is it possible to avoid this additional `hwdownload`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit in 2022:**

For those who are using Nvidia cards and want zero-copy HDR-to-SDR tone-mapping, you can now use the powerful Vulkan filter `libplacebo` that introduced in FFmpeg 5.0 to achieve this without needing the OpenCL filter.

[libplacebo](https://github.com/haasn/libplacebo) is the next-gen video renderer of the MPV player, which can perform high quality video processing including tone-mapping for HDR10 and DV content on your GPU. Since deriving from CUDA memory to Vulkan has been implemented, you can use `libplacebo` filter to chain with NVDEC, NVENC and other CUDA filters to get the best performance.

To get the additional Vulkan and libplacebo support, you must use ffmpeg that built with `--enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo`.

Prebuilt binaries can be get from https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases

A snippet of cmd to do this:

```
./ffmpeg -threads 1 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i HDR.mp4 \
-vf "scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080:interp_algo=bilinear,hwupload=derive_device=vulkan, \
libplacebo=tonemapping=auto:colorspace=bt709:color_primaries=bt709:color_trc=bt709:format=yuv420p:upscaler=none:downscaler=none:peak_detect=0, \
hwupload=derive_device=cuda" \
-c:v h264_nvenc -preset medium -profile:v high -b:v 8M -y SDR.mp4
```

What does it mean:

1. Decode the video with NVDEC HW accelerator to CUDA memory
2. Scale to video to 1080p with CUDA filter(bilinear algorithm)
3. Derive from CUDA to Vulkan memory with `hwupload`
4. Apply auto tone-map from HDR to SDR 8bit yuv420p without using libplacebo's built-in scalers for performance
5. Derive from Vulkan to CUDA memory with `hwupload`
6. Encode to H.264 1080p SDR 8M with NVENC encoder

Note that the `hwupload` here doesn't mean copy back to memory.
Instead, in this specific CUDA-Vulkan pipeline, it does the same thing like the `hwmap`. The whole video filtering pipeline is happening on your GPU and VRAM.

`upscaler=none:downscaler=none:peak_detect=0`
These three options disabled some high quality up/down-scaling algorithms and the HDR peak detection function to trade off for better performance. You can remove them for the best quality.

For more fine-tuning options in libplacebo filter, see
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#libplacebo

---

**Original answer in 2021:**

Nope at least for now.

Zero-copy texture sharing aka `hwmap` filter between Cuda and OpenCL devices is not available in ffmpeg until Nvidia releases an interop method for them.

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html

Intel and AMD have some OpenCL extensions for D3D11/VAAPI<->OpenCL interop and can split one shared image(e.g. NV12) into different planes(e.g. plane Y and UV).
Such as [`cl_intel_va_api_media_sharing`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/intel/cl_intel_d3d11_nv12_media_sharing.txt) [`cl_intel_d3d11_nv12_media_sharing`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/intel/cl_intel_d3d11_nv12_media_sharing.txt) from Intel and [`cl_amd_planar_yuv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/amd/cl_amd_planar_yuv.txt) from AMD.

As for Nvidia, they indeed have `cl_nv_d3d11_sharing` for D3D11<->OpenCL interop but I don't think it will work well when it comes to Cuda.

Another solution is to port the tone mapping algorithm as a Cuda filter but it'll take some times. Huge speed improvement can be expected once it is finished. You can use it easily like `scale_cuda` or `overlay_cuda` filter and so on.

I have seen Intel has already supported `tonemap_vaapi` filter through hardware function in their latest iGPUs. Not sure if Nvidia NVENC has a similar one in their ASIC.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Is a cuda version of the tone mapping filter currently in development or is this just hypothetical?

Comment: It's still in concept before someone make it come true. AFAIK some algorithms in tonemap_opencl is ported from libplacebo. Would be great if any Cuda & ffmpeg experts want to look into it.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the update of your answer! I'll try it out soon!